# Recursive function and Map for accessing Elements in nested Array

Tags: javascript

**Situation**

- I have an nested Array and I have a ID to search for. Like "A_02_02_01_03"
- Every Element in an array has a element called "children", that is a
  array
- My method gets pretty long when I'm searching in the 4th Layer.

**Example Array**

```
var tree= [
  {
    "name": "i2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "d1",
        "children": [],
        "id": "DW_02_01",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      },
      {
        "name": "d2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "e1",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "a1",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_01",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              },
              {
                "name": "a2",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_02",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              },
              {
                "name": "a3",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_03",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              }`enter code here`
            ],
            "id": "E_02_02_01",
            "beschreibung": "",
            "table": []
          },
          {
            "name": "e2",
            "children": [],
            "id": "E_02_02_02",
            "beschreibung": "",
            "table": []
          }
        ],
        "id": "DW_02_02",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      },
      {
        "name": "d3",
        "children": [],
        "id": "DW_02_03",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      }
    ],
    "id": "IW_02",
    "beschreibung": "",
    "table": []
  },
  {
    "name": "i3",
    "children": [],
    "id": "IW_03",
    "beschreibung": "",
    "table": []
  }
]
```

**Constructing IDs**

```
var daIW = "IW_02";
var daDW = "DW_02_02;
var daE = "E_02_02_01;
var daA = "A_02_02_01_03";
```

**Getting all my indices**

```
var iw_index = tree.findIndex(element => element.id == daIW);
var dw_index = tree[iw_index]["children"].findIndex(element => element.id == daDW);
var e_index = tree[iw_index]["children"][dw_index]["children"].findIndex(element => element.id == daE);
var a_index = tree[iw_index]["children"][dw_index]["children"][e_index]["children"].findIndex(element => element.id == daA);
```

**Accessing my Element**

```
var elementName = tree[iw_index]["children"][dw_index]["children"][e_index]["children"][a_index].name;
```

**Question**

Is there a shorter way for accessing the deepest Element "A_02_02_01_03" then searching for every index?

Comment: What is the result you're looking for? You just want to return the child that contains whatever id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: Are the `id` values on the leaf nodes (A_02_02_01_03 and such) unique? If so, any particular reason you can't just create a map of them?

Comment: @zfrisch In the End I want to change, move or delete this Element. First I wanted to get there. I was just exhausted for always writing something like this: `tree[iw_index]["children"][dw_index]["children"][e_index]["children"].splice(new_index, 0, tree[iw_index]["children"][dw_index]["children"][e_index]["children"].splice(old_index, 1)[0]);`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The IDs are unique, but I did not know about the Map concept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want recursion to search the tree deep first:

```
function search(array = [], id){
  for(const node of array){
    if(node.id === id) return node;

    const sub = search(node.children, id);
    if(sub) return sub;
  }
}
```

So you can do:

```
const result = search(tree, "A_02_02_01_03");
```

---

If you want to find multiple items, it might be better to build up a hashtable that stores all id/node pairs, so lookup is very fast then:

```
function createLookup(array, hash = new Map){
  for(const node of array){
    hash.set(node.id, node);
    createLookup(node.children, hash);
  }
  return hash;
}
```

So you can do:

```
const hash = createLookup(tree);
const result = hash.get("A_02_02_01_03");
```

Comment: This assumes the IDs of those leaf nodes are unique. From the fact the OP is using other IDs to get there, I'm not sure I'd make that assumption...

Comment: @Jonas W. Big thx for your example. Recursion was the needed concept for my brain to solve this. I also tried your hashtable example. This throws me an error: `InternalError: too much recursion`

Comment: @JamesHenry: That's just a typo in the code (`createLookup(array, hash);` should have been `createLookup(node.children, hash);`), I've fixed it.

Comment: Jonas - James [has replied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668232/other-method-for-accessing-element-in-nested-array-then-indexof?noredirect=1#comment84359661_48668232) to my question about IDs: The leaf node IDs *are* unique, so these solutions work like a charm.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thx guys for your time, I learned a lot. I tried both solutions. They work really good and made my code so much clearer and shorter.

Comment: @james glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

<s>I'm assuming that for some reason you can't just search for the entry with `id == "A_02_02_01_03"`. E.g., that you need the other IDs for some reason.</s>

Now that you've confirmed that the leaf node IDs are unique, [Jonas w's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668382/157247) which only uses the leaf node ID (e.g., `"A_02_02_01_03"`) will work. If you have those other IDs available, that can make the process faster by avoiding visiting nodes you don't need to visit, but you'd have to have a very big tree for that to matter.

If it does matter, this answer still applies:

I'd probably use a recursive function:

```
function find(node, ids, index = 0) {
    const id = ids[index];
    const entry = node.find(e => e.id == id);
    if (!entry) {
        return null;
    }
    ++index;
    return index < ids.length ? find(entry.children, ids, index) : entry;
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
const result = find(tree, [daIW, daDW, daE, daA]);
```

That assumes you want the entry as the result.

Live Example:

```js
var tree= [
  {
    "name": "i2",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "d1",
        "children": [],
        "id": "DW_02_01",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      },
      {
        "name": "d2",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "e1",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "a1",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_01",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              },
              {
                "name": "a2",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_02",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              },
              {
                "name": "a3",
                "children": [],
                "id": "A_02_02_01_03",
                "beschreibung": "",
                "table": []
              }
            ],
            "id": "E_02_02_01",
            "beschreibung": "",
            "table": []
          },
          {
            "name": "e2",
            "children": [],
            "id": "E_02_02_02",
            "beschreibung": "",
            "table": []
          }
        ],
        "id": "DW_02_02",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      },
      {
        "name": "d3",
        "children": [],
        "id": "DW_02_03",
        "beschreibung": "",
        "table": []
      }
    ],
    "id": "IW_02",
    "beschreibung": "",
    "table": []
  },
  {
    "name": "i3",
    "children": [],
    "id": "IW_03",
    "beschreibung": "",
    "table": []
  }
];

var daIW = "IW_02";
var daDW = "DW_02_02";
var daE = "E_02_02_01";
var daA = "A_02_02_01_03";

function find(node, ids, index = 0) {
    const id = ids[index];
    const entry = node.find(e => e.id == id);
    if (!entry) {
        return null;
    }
    ++index;
    return index < ids.length ? find(entry.children, ids, index) : entry;
}

console.log(find(tree, [daIW, daDW, daE, daA]));
```

Comment: This is actually a good reduce usecase imo: `ids.reduce((node, id) => node.children.find(child => child.id === id), tree)`

Comment: @JonasW.: If we were using the same ID for each level. I imagine we could shoe-horn it into a `reduce` even if using different IDs for different levels, but it's clearer if we don't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is a great example to search with a recursive function multiple IDs. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following recursive function

//Function

```
  function getelement(vtree, id) {
      vtree.forEach(function(treeitem) {
        if(treeitem["id"] === id) {
            console.log(treeitem);
        }
        else if(treeitem["children"].length){
            getelement(treeitem["children"], id);
        }
    });
  };
```

//Caller

```
getelement(tree,"A_02_02_01_03");
```